# C# Multiple objects using timer

Tags: c#, timer

Ok, so I have a list of fixtures, fixtures can be played at the same time. A fixture lasts for 10 minutes and has random events every few seconds.

Now lets say I have 5 fixtures being played at the same time, how can I use a timer so that each fixture runs in parallel and uses same event for checking random events during the 10 mintues

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I guess what Andy tries to say is: your question is unclear now. Some code may help clarify the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea would be to create a static timer inside your class at the same level as your methods inside this class meaning the timer is accessible from anywhere inside this class and even from outside the class if it is public.

```
namespace abc
{
     public class xyz
     {
          public static Timer t;

          public void method1()
          {
              //Check for timer-time and do stuff
          }

          public void method2()
          {
              //Check for timer-time and do stuff
          }

          //and so on ...
     }
}
```

And start this timer via `t.start();` after you created all of your fixtures.
Now inside of each fixture you do something when the timer does a tick event.

Note that this just works when you create all of your fixtures at the same time, so their lifetime is the exact same (they are created at the same moment and they "die" at the same moment, for your example after 10 minutes). I hope this is what you mean when you say "parallel".

If this has nothing to do with your problem and I understood something completly wrong please give us some code and we will provide (hopefully) better answers.